# React / NextJS: limit the rendering of a component and update props instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a NextJS application that displays a list of audio tracks through a component called `<AudioTrackEntry>`. This component receives props such as the Track Title and a Link to the audio file through a mapping from an external data source.

Nested within the `<AudioTrackEntry>` component is the `<AudioPlayer>` that is toggled through a play button.

This currently results in multiple (overlapping) audio players being rendered, when play buttons on multiple audio track entries are being clicked. Clicking 3 Play buttons on 3 tracks result in 3 audio tracks simultaneously playing.

**The behaviour I had intended was to just update the respective props of trackTitle and trackLink.**

*I assume that the reason why the player is being re-rendered is that I'm toggling the visibility state of the AudioPlayer component, and when the state changes, the component gets re-rendered.*

**How can I limit the button toggle to only update the props of trackTitle and trackLink, not render another player here?**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import AudioPlayer from './AudioPlayer';

interface AudioTrackEntryProps {
  trackLink: any;
  trackClaimStatus: any;
  trackTitle: any;
  trackDuration: any;
  trackBPM: any;
  trackGenre: any;
  trackClaimAmount: any;
}

const AudioTrackEntry: React.FC<AudioTrackEntryProps> = (props) => {


  const [activeTrack, setActiveTrack] = useState('');

  const toggleAudioPlayer = (trackTitle: string) => {
    setActiveTrack(activeTrack === '' ? trackTitle : '');
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4 border-b border-cllinegray p-2">
        <div className="col-span-1 flex items-center">
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              toggleAudioPlayer(props.trackTitle);
            }}
            className="border-transparent bg-transparent hover:border-transparent"
          >
            Play </button>
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-3 flex items-center">
          <h4 className="m-0 font-bold uppercase">{props.trackTitle}</h4>
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-1 m-auto text-neutral-300">
          <p>{props.trackDuration}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-1 m-auto text-neutral-300">
          <p>{props.trackBPM}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-1 m-auto text-neutral-300">
          <p>{props.trackGenre}</p>
        </div>

        <div className="col-span-1 m-auto text-xs text-neutral-300">
          <InstrumentalButton />
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-1 m-auto text-xs text-neutral-300">
          <RemixButton />
        </div>
    
     

      {activeTrack === props.trackTitle && (
        <AudioPlayer
          trackLink={props.trackLink}
          trackTitle={activeTrack}
          trackDuration={props.trackDuration}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default AudioTrackEntry;
```

Here is the code of the `<AudioPlayer>` component:

```
import {
  MediaControlBar,
  MediaController,
  MediaMuteButton,
  MediaPlayButton,
  MediaTimeDisplay,
  MediaTimeRange,
  MediaVolumeRange,
} from 'media-chrome/dist/react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import React from 'react';

import TrackIcon from '@/public/assets/images/icons/track_icon.svg';

function AudioPlayer(props: {
  trackLink: any;
  trackTitle: string;
  trackDuration: string | number;
}) {
  return (
    <div className="fixed inset-x-0 bottom-0 z-30 rounded-md bg-neutral-900 p-6">
      <div className="flex">
        <div className="w-1/12">
          <Image src={TrackIcon} alt="Full Circus" />
        </div>

        <div className="flex w-3/12 items-center">
          <h4 className="font-bold uppercase">{props.trackTitle} </h4>
        </div>

        <div className="mx-auto flex w-8/12 items-center">
          <MediaController audio className="w-full bg-neutral-900">
            <audio src={props.trackLink} autoPlay slot="media"></audio>
            <MediaControlBar className="bg-neutral-900">
              <MediaPlayButton className="bg-transparent"></MediaPlayButton>
              <MediaTimeRange className="w-80 bg-transparent"></MediaTimeRange>
              <MediaTimeDisplay
                className="w-32 bg-transparent font-trade"
                showDuration
              ></MediaTimeDisplay>
              <div className="mx-24 flex">
                <MediaMuteButton className="bg-transparent"></MediaMuteButton>
                <MediaVolumeRange className="w-80 bg-transparent"></MediaVolumeRange>
              </div>
            </MediaControlBar>
          </MediaController>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AudioPlayer;
```

Comment: It's likely that the problem is actually in the `AudioPlayer` itself – make sure that it stops playing when it is unmounted.

Comment: This still results in the rendering of multiple players.

Comment: Your code here to toggle the visibility of the `AudioPlayer` will only ever result in one instance of the `AudioPlayer` component being rendered at any time. If there are side-effects within the `AudioPlayer` (such as the playing of audio) then those may continue outside the time that the component is actually rendered. Would recommend including the `AudioPlayer` code – it doesn't seem that the bug is in the code that you shared.

Comment: Code of the Audio Player was added.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the question. Full answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to move the state that controls the "active track" to a component higher up the component tree than all your `AudioPlayer` instances, and pass the appropriate state-setter down. For instance,

```js
interface AudioTrackDetails {
  trackLink: any;
  trackClaimStatus: any;
   ... etc
}

const AudioTrackList: FC<{ availableTracks: AudioTrackDetails[] }> =
  ({ availableTracks }) =>
  {
    const [activeTrackTitle, setActiveTrackTitle] = useState<string | null>(null);
    return <>{ availableTracks.map(entry =>
      <AudioTrackEntry {...entry} key={activeTrack.trackTitle}
        activeTrackTitle={activeTrackTitle}
        setActiveTrack={setActiveTrackTitle}
      />
    }</>
  }

interface AudioTrackEntryProps extends AudioTrackDetails {
  activeTrackTitle: string | null;
  setActiveTrackTitle: (newTrack: (oldTrack: string | null) => string | null) => void;
}

const AudioTrackEntry: React.FC<AudioTrackEntryProps> = (props) =>
{
  const toggleAudioPlayer = (trackTitle: string) => {
    setActiveTrackTitle(
      oldTitle => oldTitle !== trackTitle ? trackTitle : ""
    );
  };
  ...
}
```

This essentially gives you a mutex controlled by this parent `AudioTrackList` which ensures that only one (or zero) of the `AudioTrackEntry` instances can exist at a time. If the user toggles an inactive track then it hides the currently-active track; if the user toggles the active track then it stops playing altogether.

Comment: Took me a little more tweaking, but you Sir are a genius.